# How to combine SQL query statements to get all related rows based on first query?

Tags: sqlite

I got this SQL statement :

```
SELECT id, gamenumber, title, name, points FROM `games` where name = 'Tom Smith'
```

which extracts all games for `'Tom Smith'` which he participated in.  My issue is that a `gamenumber` can have many players (e.g. `gamenumber` 1 can have 4 different players) that Tom played against.

How would I in SQL be able to get games Tom played, and then get all records with the same `gameid` per game Tom played ?

If Tom played one game with 4 players :

```
SELECT id, gamenumber, title, name, points FROM `games` where name = 'Tom Smith'

SELECT * from games where gamenumber = <gamenumber from Tom's single game>
```

This would give me all records from his single game, but how can I do this in one SQL command ?

Comment: I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the rows for the `gamenumber`s that Tom had played, use a subquery to get them and apply it in a IN clause:

```
select id, gamenumber, title, name, points 
from `games` 
where gamenumber in ( 
  select gamenumber
  from `games`
  where name = 'Tom Smith'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either nested queries (i.e. subqueries) or [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_with.html).

I prefer CTE because it makes the primary query a bit cleaner and they can be referenced multiple times in the same query.

```
WITH TomGames AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT gamenumber
    FROM games
    WHERE name = 'Tom Smith')

SELECT id, gamenumber, title, name, points 
FROM games
    INNER JOIN TomGames
    ON games.gamenumber = TomGames.gamenumber;
```